# How to read (std::io::Read) from a Vec or Slice?

Tags: io, rust, traits

`Vec`s support `std::io::Write`, so code can be written that takes a `File` or `Vec`, for example. From the API reference, it looks like neither `Vec` nor slices support `std::io::Read`.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this? Does it require writing a wrapper struct?

Here is an example of working code, that reads and writes a file, with a single line commented that should read a vector.

```
use ::std::io;

// Generic IO
fn write_4_bytes<W>(mut file: W) -> Result<usize, io::Error>
    where W: io::Write,
{
    let len = file.write(b"1234")?;
    Ok(len)
}

fn read_4_bytes<R>(mut file: R) -> Result<[u8; 4], io::Error>
    where R: io::Read,
{
    let mut buf: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
    file.read(&mut buf)?;
    Ok(buf)
}

// Type specific

fn write_read_vec() {
    let mut vec_as_file: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

    {   // Write
        println!("Writing Vec... {}", write_4_bytes(&mut vec_as_file).unwrap());
    }

    {   // Read
//      println!("Reading File... {:?}", read_4_bytes(&vec_as_file).unwrap());
        //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //                               Comment this line above to avoid an error!
    }
}

fn write_read_file() {
    let filepath = "temp.txt";
    {   // Write
        let mut file_as_file = ::std::fs::File::create(filepath).expect("open failed");
        println!("Writing File... {}", write_4_bytes(&mut file_as_file).unwrap());
    }

    {   // Read
        let mut file_as_file = ::std::fs::File::open(filepath).expect("open failed");
        println!("Reading File... {:?}", read_4_bytes(&mut file_as_file).unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    write_read_vec();
    write_read_file();
}
```

This fails with the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:42
   |
29 |         println!("Reading File... {:?}", read_4_bytes(&vec_as_file).unwrap());
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
   |
   = note: required by `read_4_bytes`
```

I'd like to write tests for a file format encoder/decoder, without having to write to the file-system.

Comment: I have deleted my answer. This question is now _substantially bigger_ and provides _alot more context_ than when originally asked.

Comment: @simon-whitehead, apologies for not giving a comprehensive question initially, I thought there might be some totally obvious thing I was missing which didn't require working code example.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

While vectors don't support `std::io::Read`, slices do.

There is some confusion here caused by Rust being able to coerce a `Vec` into a slice in some situations but not others.

In this case, an explicit coercion to a slice is needed because at the stage coercions are applied, the compiler doesn't know that `Vec<u8>` *doesn't* implement `Read`.

---

The code in the question will work when the vector is coerced into a slice  using one of the following methods:

- `read_4_bytes(&*vec_as_file)`
- `read_4_bytes(&vec_as_file[..])`
- `read_4_bytes(vec_as_file.as_slice())`.

---

Note:

- When asking the question initially, I was taking `&Read` instead of `Read`. This made passing a reference to a slice fail, unless I'd passed in `&&*vec_as_file` which I didn't think to do.
- Recent versions of rust you can also use `as_slice()` to convert a Vec to a slice.
- *Thanks to @arete on `#rust` for finding the solution!*

Comment: In more recent versions of rust you can also use `as_slice()` to convert a `Vec` to a slice and then you can use methods from `Read`.

Answer (score 49):

## std::io::Cursor

`std::io::Cursor` is a simple and useful wrapper that implements `Read` for `Vec<u8>`, so it allows to use vector as a readable entity.

```
let mut file = Cursor::new(vector);

read_something(&mut file);
```

And [documentation](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#examples) shows how to use `Cursor` instead of `File` to write unit-tests!

Working example:

```
use std::io::Cursor;
use std::io::Read;

fn read_something(file: &mut impl Read) {
    let _ = file.read(&mut [0; 8]);
}

fn main() {
    let vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let mut file = Cursor::new(vector);

    read_something(&mut file);
}
```

From the [documentation](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) about `std::io::Cursor`:

> Cursors are typically used with in-memory buffers to allow them to implement `Read` and/or `Write`...
>
> The standard library implements some I/O traits on various types which are commonly used as a buffer, like `Cursor<Vec<u8>>` and `Cursor<&[u8]>`.

---

## Slice

The example above works for **slices** as well. In that case it would look like the following:

```
read_something(&mut &vector[..]);
```

Working example:

```
use std::io::Read;

fn read_something(file: &mut impl Read) {
    let _ = file.read(&mut [0; 8]);
}

fn main() {
    let vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    read_something(&mut &vector[..]);
}
```

`&mut &vector[..]` is a "mutable reference to a slice" (a reference to a reference to a part of vector), so I just find the explicit option with `Cursor` to be more clear and elegant.

---

## Cursor <-> Slice

Even more: if you have a `Cursor` that owns a buffer, and you need to emulate, for instance, a part of a "file", you can get a `slice` from the `Cursor` and pass to the function.

```
read_something(&mut &file.get_ref()[1..3]);
```